# Academic prospect survey

Tags: survey-research

Is there any survey which shows the schools that current professors have attended in the past?

For example, "10% of current tenure positions in EU are held by Cambridge PhD graduates"

I'm interested in theoretical physics and I'd like to know if there is any way of finding such information.

Comment: For a sufficiently small sample you could compile that statistic yourself. Professors have websites and having a CV on them is common, so you can usually find out where a particular professor graduated from.

Comment: Yes, I'm more interested in statistics rather than specific cases

Comment: I suspect that if you are trying to find some correlation, it would be very minor. There are as many universities that have tenure position on a field as there are universities with PhD students in the same field. Its likely that with such particular small population, correlation would not pass significance values. I might be wrong.